# After electron-build node-adodb got error: 'Spawn C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I was using node-adodb.js to read .mdb files.  code :

```
const db = require('node-adodb')

ipcMain.on('query', (e, p) => {

if (!p) return


appendFileSync('a.log', new Date().getTime() + ' ' + p.table + ' \r\n')

let conn = db.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=' + p.path)

conn.query('select ID,品种,批号,日期,包重,条码 from ' + p.table  + ' order by ID')

.then(data => {

  e.sender.send('result', data)

  appendFileSync('a.log', data.length + ' ' + p.table + ' \r\n')

 })

 .catch(err => {

   appendFileSync('a.log', JSON.stringify(err) + ' \r\n')

 })

})
```

part of package.json:

```
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "asar": false,
  "extraResources": [
    {
      "from": "./node_modules/node-adodb/lib/adodb.js",
      "to": "adodb.js"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
```

It worked perfectly on runtime, but when I built it and run the exe, I got

> Spawn C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error
>   {"exitMessage":"Uncaught Fatal Exception","exitCode":1}

I had made some changes, but it didn't seem to work
[changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aul9F.png)

versions：
node v12.12.0
electron-builder@21.2.0
electron@6.1.7
vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder@1.4.4

so, is there anyone could help me out this problem?

Comment: That's not much to go on.  Do you know which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: maybe 'conn.query', it needs 'child_process.spawn'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

you have to

```
import {app} from 'electron'
import ADODB from 'node-adodb';
if (app.isPackaged) { ADODB.PATH = './resources/adodb.js'; }
```

and in package.json

```
 "build": {
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "./node_modules/node-adodb/lib/adodb.js",
    "to": "adodb.js"
  }
]
```

To use node-adodb from electron

Following [this boilerplate](https://blog.stranianelli.com/ms-access-electron-construct-3-english/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the above answer didn't worked as is.

in *package.json* add the following:

```json
"build": {
    ...
    "extraResources": [
      "./assets/**",
      {
        "from": "./node_modules/node-adodb/lib/adodb.js",
        "to": "adodb.js"
      }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Then, in each file you need `adodb`:

```js
const ADODB = require("node-adodb");

///It's only needed to change the path in production. Otherwise in dev it won't work. 
///Something like process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" can be used
if (!isAppDebug()) {
  ADODB.PATH = "./resources/adodb.js";
}
```

Tested with *electron@20.3.7* and *node-adodb@5.0.3*